# Conditionally fallback to different join condition if stricter condition not matched

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I have 2 tables j and c.

Both tables have columns ports and sec, and JOIN ON j.ports = c.ports and c.sec = j.sec.

For `j.port = 'ABC'`, if there is no `c.sec = j.sec` for the same ports, then JOIN ON `LEFT(c.sec, 6) = LEFT(j.sec, 6)`

For other `j.ports`, I only want to join ON `j.ports = c.ports and c.sec = j.sec`

How can I do that?

**Example Data**

**Table c**

```
+------+------------+------------+
| Port |    sec     |   Other    |
+------+------------+------------+
| ABC  | abcdefghij |  ONE       |
| ABC  | klmnop     |  TWO       |
| LMN  | qwertyuiop |  THREE     |
| XYZ  | asdfghjkl  |  FOUR      |
+------+------------+------------+
```

**Table j**

```
+------+------------+
| Port |    sec     |
+------+------------+
| ABC  | abcdefxxxx |
| ABC  | klmnop     |
| LMN  | qwertyuiop |
| XYZ  | zxcvbnm    |
+------+------------+
```

**EDITED: Desired Results**

```
+------+------------+------------+
| Port |    sec     |  other     |
+------+------------+------------+
| ABC  | abcdefghij |  ONE       |  --> mactching on sec's 1st 6 characters 
| ABC  | klmnop     |  TWO       |  --> mactching on sec
| LMN  | qwertyuiop |  THREE     |  --> mactching on sec
+------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: How is this different to your other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55837372/different-join-values-depending-on-the-value-of-another-column)

Comment: Please show us a complete query, sample data, current result data and expected result data.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: It is different as the first one had static rules for the different join conditions. This one depends on the result of the join then falls back to a different condition if no rows matched. The existing answers there don't answer this. It is a different question.

Comment: What are you able to do? Give a [mcve]. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Dumps of specifications are not on-topic SO questions.

Comment: Thank you all. I have edited the original post with desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This does conditional joining:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from j t1 inner join c t2
on t2.ports = t1.ports and
  case 
    when exists (select 1 from c where sec = t1.sec) then t1.sec 
    else left(t1.sec, 6) 
  end =
  case 
    when exists (select 1 from c where sec = t1.sec) then t2.sec 
    else left(t2.sec, 6) 
  end
```

I question its efficiency but I think it does what you need.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c8f2199fb6b1c9319ea0c7099e149a90).

Answer (score 0):

You can do two outer joins and then do isnull type of operation.  In oracle nvl is isnull of sqlserver

```
with c as 
(
    select 'ABC' port, 'abcdefghij' sec from dual
    union all select 'ABC', 'klmnop' from dual 
    union all select 'LMN', 'qwertyuiop' from dual
    union all select 'XYZ', 'asdfghjkl' from dual
),
j as 
(
    select 'ABC' port, 'abcdefxxxx' sec from dual
    union all select 'ABC', 'klmnop' from dual 
    union all select 'LMN', 'qwertyuiop' from dual
    union all select 'XYZ', 'zxcvbnm' from dual
)
select c.port, c.sec, nvl(j_full.sec, j_part.sec) j_sec
from c
     left outer join j j_full on j_full.port = c.port and j_full.sec = c.sec
     left outer join j j_part on j_part.port = c.port and substr(j_part.sec,1,6) = substr(c.sec,1,6)
order by 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to just inner join on the less strict predicate then use a ranking function to discard unwanted rows in the event that `c.port = 'ABC'` and the stricter condition got a match for a particular `c.port, c.sec` combination.

```
with cte as
(
select c.port as cPort, 
       c.sec as cSec, 
       c.other as other,
       j.sec as jSec, 
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY c.port, c.sec ORDER BY CASE WHEN c.port = 'ABC' AND j.sec = c.sec THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS rnk
from c inner join  j on left(j.sec,6) = left(c.sec,6)
)
SELECT cPort, cSec, other, jSec
FROM cte 
WHERE rnk = 1
```